# Saving values from recurring function into file

Tags: c#, file, streamwriter, recurrence

I have this piece of code written in C# (it's part of implementation of ID3 algorithm)

```
public static void printNode(TreeNode root, string tabs, ref StreamWriter xa)
{
    //Console.ReadKey();

    Console.WriteLine(tabs + '|' + root.attribute + '|');

    if (root.attribute.values != null)
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < root.attribute.values.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tabs + "\t" + "<" + root.attribute.values[i] + ">");
                xa.WriteLine(tabs + "\n" + root.attribute.values[i] +"\n");

                TreeNode childNode = root.getChildByBranchName(root.attribute.values[i]);
                printNode(childNode, "\t" + tabs, ref xa);
            }
    }
}
```

I also have this declaration.

```
StreamWriter xa = new StreamWriter("tree1.txt");
```

And issue is that after running code file 'tree1.txt' is always empty. Any idea how to handle this? As you can see I tried references cause it seems to me like right course of action but I don't really know much about C# and recurrence function behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the StreamWriter to force it to flush to disk.

You also need to look in the current directory, which might not be what you think it is.

Comment: Current directory is what I think it is.
And closing StreamWriter, when should I do it? When I try to open it and close at every recursion it says that file is already used when I try to compile the code.

Comment: Ok I just found out, I have not closed StreamWriter at all... Just once, at end of the program was enough.